# executing a command from a string and timing it

Tags: python, linux, bash, csv, timing

I need to write a script that will receive several parameters, from which the most important one
Is a string that contains a command (in linux).

I need to be able to run it, keep the output in STDOUT (the usual), but also time it, and later output some .csv file.

Say it looks something like this:

`timing_script.py param "echo hello world; cat /tmp/foo_bar"`

The command will output stuff to STDOUT every couple of milliseconds, which I need it to stay there. I'm saying this because my previous attempt at this script was in `bash` and I had to `cut` from the `time` command to actually time that, which also meant having to disregard the output of the command.

I'll also have to append something like `param,0.345` to a csv file.

How do I execute a command from a string and also time it?

Comment: `bash -c "time test_command" >/tmp/logfile 2>&1` & then `head -n -4 < /tmp/logfile > /tmp/stdout-err` `tail -n 4 < /tmp/logfile > /tmp/timing-data`.

Comment: @anishane : Looks like an overkill suggestion. Plus using temporary files when unnecessary may lead to unexpected behaviors (just think about running multiple times your command with different "test_command")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `subprocess` to run linux command from string and `time` to calculate execution time:

```py
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

start = time.time()

p1 = Popen(["my_linux_cmd"], stdout=PIPE)
print(p1.communicate()) # sdout

end = time.time()
exec_time = end - start
print(exec_time) # exeution time
```

Check [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) fro more details about the available options

***Warning:*** to print the stdout you can also use `Popen.stdout.read` but use `communicate()` rather to avoid **deadlocks** due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way which stays in the shell uses the formatting option `-f` of the `time` command. You can use it like that :

```
$ param="foo"
$ command="echo bar ; cat /tmp/foobar"
$ /usr/bin/time -f "$param,%e" bash -c "$command"
bar
#Beginning of foobar file
#End of foobar file
foo,0.00
```

Please have a look at `man time` for further examples about formatting the output of `time`

Of course, you can also directly run the following command (i.e. without using variables) :

```
/usr/bin/time -f "myparam,%e" bash -c "echo bar ; cat /tmp/foobar"
```

Have fun

Comment: The `time` command you're talking about is the one that's usually in `/usr/bin/time` which is missing from my working environment... That was one of my problems with writing the original bash scripts. The `time` I have is the built in time in unix.

Comment: yep that's right. I modified my answer accordingly. If `/usr/bin/time` is not available for you ... you may go for Python :). I let my answer because it may be of interest for people you have `/usr/bin/time`.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the answer anyway, hope your edit will help someone :)